# CRC32 on SAM D20 (Cortex M0+)

Tags: microcontroller, c, cortex-m, crc

I've been having a hard time debugging the DSU module on a SAM D20 ([datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/atmel-42129-sam-d20_datasheet.pdf)). I mean to utilize it to calculate CRC32 for a program I'm uploading through a custom bootloader (bootloader not mine).

Here is the code:

```
// enable DSU module - enable its clocks
PM->AHBMASK.reg |= PM_AHBMASK_DSU;
PM->APBBMASK.reg |= PM_APBBMASK_DSU;

// enable writes to DSU
PAC1->WPCLR.reg = 0x02;

// configure Addr and Length registers
DSU->DATA.reg = 0xFFFFFFFFUL;
DSU->ADDR.reg |= DSU_ADDR_ADDR(address);
DSU->LENGTH.reg = DSU_LENGTH_LENGTH(nbytes/4); // length should be in words

DSU->STATUSA.bit.DONE = 1; // clear the done bit
DSU->CTRL.bit.CRC = 1; // begin CRC calculation

// wait until done
while(!DSU->STATUSA.bit.DONE);

// read CRC out of Data register
volatile uint32_t crc = (DSU->DATA.reg) ^ 0xFFFFFFFFUL;

return crc;
```

Where `address` and `nbytes` correspond to the program I'm uploading. The variable names come from the ASF library, but they are pretty self explanatory about what they mean on the datasheet.

the problem is that it won't match a CRC32 generated previously from Python's zlib module:

```
crc32 = zlib.crc32(bindata, 0xFFFFFFFF) & 0xFFFFFFFF
```

I wish I knew what questions to ask but I am not used to debugging a hardware system. So what could be wrong?

EDIT: I finally figured it out. The address register needs to be configured with a WORD address:

```
DSU->ADDR.reg |= DSU_ADDR_ADDR(address >> 2);
```

Hope this helps someone eventually.

Comment: This may be due to the different libraries using different versions of CRC32 output representation.  It looks like you are inverting the bits, but they could also be bit swapped or something similar.

Comment: I just had a quick look at it looks like the polynomial is different from the value `0xEDB88320` in the datasheet. I've never used Python but if it's possible to call C code from it somehow maybe try this code: http://www.cs.miami.edu/~burt/learning/Csc609.022/src/crc/crc-32.c

Comment: Supposedly the polynomial used in zlib is the reversed representation of `0xEDB88320` (`0x04C11DB7`). If so I thought I would just have to reverse the output. Alas, that didn't work.

Comment: @caveman - I thought that might be the case. But I have tried all kinds of permutations on the output, and could not get any to match up. I inverted the output because that's what the datasheet called for, but neither the inverted nor noninverted representation would match up with a predetermined one from Python

Comment: Hi all, I actually did figure it out just now. It was very stupid: the hardware needs a word address, not byte address.